# Laplace equation in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the Laplace equation in polar coordinates $u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0$ within the domain $0<\theta<\pi, 1<r<2$ subject to boundary conditions $$u(r,0)=0=u(r,\pi), ~~~u(1,\theta)=\sin(\theta),~~~u(2,\theta)=0$$

Remark: I approached it by using separation of variables, letting $u(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ and following the routine steps it led to a general expression which would never satisfy the condition $u(2,\theta)=0.$ Could anyone please confirm that this equation is indeed solvable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you find for $R(r)$? I have $$R(r) = \frac{C_1}{r} + C_2r$$ which can be solved to meet the boundary conditions.

---

Separating variables:

$$r^2 \frac{R''}{R} + r \frac{R'}{R} = -\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}$$

Both sides are equal to a constant, call it $k$. By the second boundary condition, $u(1,\theta)=\sin(\theta)$, we have that $k = 1$.

The equation in $R$ is $r^2R'' + rR' - kR = 0$. The is a 'homogeneous' equation, in one of the uses of that word, for ODEs. Substitute $S(r) = R(r)/r$, do some work, and you'll find the form for $R(r)$ above. Be careful when integrating to make sure you get both constants; perhaps that's what tripped you up.

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake when solvin for $R$. The solution is $\left(\frac{4}{3r}-\frac{r}{3}\right)\sin (\theta)$